# php - session, check for admin

Tags: php

I have everything working on my login except for the admin user.

When I try to navigate to my admin.php I get "Must be logged in" even if I am already logged in as an admin.

When I click the admin link, I first go to checkAdmin.php which is the code below.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['userEmail'] != 'admin@hotmail.com') {
    echo "<center><font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red>Must be logged in</font> <br><a href=index.php>Login Here</a></center>";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Am I doing something wrong on this?
Thanks.

I have session_start(); at the top of my admin.php page.
I used print_r($_SESSION); and got this line, so it has the right value.

```
Array ( [userEmail] => admin@hotmail.com )
```

Also, if I add session_start(); to the checkAdmin.php then the screen just sits at checkAdmin, when I click to go to the admin page.

The admin.php has this at the top

```
session_start();
require "checkAdmin.php";
include("db_info.php");
```

Comment: If you're relying on that `session_start()` in the `admin.php` you should probably be using `include("checkAdmin.php");` instead of `require`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have called `session_start()` before checking session variables.

Comment: I personally use `if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }` since it sometimes might cause some errors.

Comment: Then I would do what endo.anaconda says and dump the $_SESSION variable to see if there is anything in it.

Comment: When I put session_start(); I just get stuck at the checkAdmin.php page.

Comment: @Meowbits Where are you trying to point the browser after the checkAdmin.php page? Did you set up a redirect to the other page? Maybe you should `include` checkAdmin.php on your admin.php page.

Comment: I updated the main post at the bottom to show where I am calling the checkAdmin.php I do it at the very start of the admin.php page.

Answer (score 2):

- you probably did not set `$_SESSION['userEmail']` while the login-process
- also `session_start()` has to be called.
- I'd check what really is in your session with `print_r($_SESSION);`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add `session_start()` ? You have to do it before looking for session variables.

Try with it :

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['userEmail'] != 'admin@hotmail.com') {
    echo "<center><font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red>Must be logged in</font> <br><a href=index.php>Login Here</a></center>";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Tried that, I just get stuck at the checkAdmin.php page then.

Answer (score 1):

use var_dump() instead of print_r. pay carefull attention to the reported string length, because some characters arent visible, but will obviously cause a string comparison to fail.

you likely have a stray whitespace character

Comment: Using that I get a return on -- array(1) { ["userEmail"]=> string(17) "admin@hotmail.com" }